# XML validation comparing sums of two different types of childnode

Tags: xml, xsd

I am working on a file of purchasing transactions.
Each transaction may be charged to one or more accounts, and allocated to one or more categories.
For example, the following is valid:

```
<Purchase ID="1000" Date="2014-10-22">
   <AccountCharge Account="CreditVoucher">40</AccountCharge>
   <AccountCharge Account="Visa">160</AccountCharge>
   <CategoryCharge Category="Repair">150</CategoryCharge>
   <CategoryCharge Category="Parts">20</CategoryCharge>
   <CategoryCharge Category="Labour">30</CategoryCharge>
</Purchase>
```

This is valid because the sum of the AccountCharges = 200, and the sum of the CategoryCharges = 200.

Using XSD, how can this be rule be expressed?

I assume it is something close to:

```
<xs:assert test="sum(AccountCharge)=sum(CategoryCharge)" />
```

I couldn't find a listing of which functions can be used in XSD, so I'm not sure if 'sum' actually exists, or if this is the correct syntax for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xsd:assert` is actually correct as you have it.  Just add it to a complete 1.1 XSD as shown below, and you're good to go.

Note that the expressions that can be used in `xsd:assert` are basically XPath 2.0 expressions.  (Strictly speaking, there's a subset of XPath 2.0 expressions which can be used; if you hit such boundary conditions, you can pull back or sometimes configure your processor to allow full XPath 2.0 expressions in `xsd:assert`.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="Purchase">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AccountCharge" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                <xs:attribute name="Account"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="CategoryCharge" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                <xs:attribute name="Category"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="ID"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Date"/>
      <xs:assert test="sum(AccountCharge)=sum(CategoryCharge)" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks.      I hadn't been able to make this work, and thought the issue was the syntax of the assert.     Now, it seems the issue is with EditiX.     As far as I can understand, it does not support xs:assert.      {As a side note, I do NOT recommend EditiX for those new to XML Schema.      It may be powerful and effective in the hands of those strong in XML schema, but personally I find it's error messages quite cryptic.}

Comment: If EditiX does not accept the above XSD as valid, then it does not support XSD 1.1, which it must to support `xs:assert`.